# load functions in for loop - variable functionname[variable]

Tags: javascript, function

Is it possible to name a function as an array[x]?

I search for a solution to load diferent functions in a for loop.
I will declare the function like this functionnamename. And than i will call the functions in a foor loop with an array = ["name", ...];

```
function functionname["aaa"]() {
console.log("is for aaa");
}

array = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
functionname[array[i]]();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign functions as members of an object:

```
let myObj = {
    "aaa": function () {
        console.log("is for aaa");
    },
    "bbb": function () {
        console.log("is for bbb");
    }
};

myObj["ccc"] = function () {
        console.log("is for ccc");
    };

array = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    myObj[array[i]]();
}
```

Comment: i like this. and i have found a solution with array.

Comment: ... with array don't work. works only with a object.

Comment: @Malama Don't forget to accept the answer that helped you the most by clicking on the grey checkmark (✔) next to the answer. This helps people see that the answer was solved from the search results, and also gives the answerer some reputation points. You can also upvote any answers that helped you. See: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly, you want to loop through an array of functions, calling the function in the array that is located at the index of the current iteration in the loop.

I have no idea what your goal is, but here is one possible solution, although there are a few ways you can approach this:

```js
const aaa = () => console.log('aaa');
const bbb = () => console.log('bbb');
const ccc = () => console.log('ccc');

const array = [aaa, bbb, ccc];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i]();
}
```

Comment: thanks also! but, thats a little bit to much for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create lookup table of functions.

```
let functionname = {
    "aaa": () => {
        console.log("is for aaa")
    },
    "bbb": () => {
        console.log("is for bbb")
    }
};
```

without arrow functions:

```
var functionname = {
    "aaa": function aaa() {
        console.log("is for aaa");
    },
    "bbb": function bbb() {
        console.log("is for bbb");
    }
};
```

Comment: also nice. i had make the failure to not initiale the array functionname.

Comment: functionname is not an array but an object in this case. In javascript you cannot use string indexes with arrays. You can create array of functions but then you have to use integer indexes.

Comment: i have detected yet. see my solution in my answer - don't work. with array don't work. with object works.

Comment: "integer indexes"... yet i understand it... it's not PHP, it's JS! my most common mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Do it in such a way, otherwise you would need to use functions such as [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) or the [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) constructor to parse strings.

```
function commonfunction(name){
 console.log('is for '+name);
}

var array = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"];

array = array.map((name)=>()=>commonfunction(name));
array.forEach((_newFunction)=>_newFunction());
```